# Limit product to value types in scala

Tags: scala

In scala I have a constructor for a class that takes a list of Products. I am using products because I want the items in the list to all have a certain length. Is there any way to also have type restrictions on the Product? For example, I want every item in the product to be an AnyVal.

I don't think this is possible. Are there any good alternatives? I could have a list of Vector[AnyVal] and then check the length of each vector in the constructor, but I would prefer that the length by enforced by the type.

Comment: There is https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless that could fit the bill. You may also be able to encode the constraint with an implicit argument. Some code snippet of what you are ideally trying to achieve may help.

Comment: @huynhjl How would I accomplish this with an implicit argument?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are exactly trying to do. From the short description it looks like this would even work: `type P3 = Product3[AnyVal, AnyVal, AnyVal]; class C(list: List[P3]); new C(List((1,2,3), ("a", "b", "c")): List[P3])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless).

For example,

```
trait T
class A extends T
class Q[X <: T, N <: shapeless.Nat](xs: shapeless.Sized[Seq[Int],N]) {}
new Q(shapeless.Sized(new A, new A))
```

will do what you want (and restrict types to subclasses of `T`--`AnyVal` works also).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the scala type system to restrict your types to AnyVals:

```
scala> val p:Product4[AnyVal,AnyVal,AnyVal,AnyVal] =(1,2,3,4)
p: Product4[AnyVal,AnyVal,AnyVal,AnyVal] = (1,2,3,4)

scala> val p:Product4[AnyVal,AnyVal,AnyVal,AnyVal] =(1,2,3,new Object)
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Object
 required: AnyVal
```

Example:

```
scala> class RestrictedClass (l:List[Product2[AnyVal,AnyVal]])
defined class RestrictedClass

scala> val i = List((1,2),(3,4),(new Object,5))
i: List[(Any, Int)] = List((1,2), (3,4), (java.lang.Object@15d1b97,5))

scala> new RestrictedClass(i)
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[(Any, Int)]
 required: List[Product2[AnyVal,AnyVal]]
          new RestrictedClass(i)
                              ^
scala> val i2 = List((1,2),(3,4),(5,6))
i2: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))

scala> new RestrictedClass(i2)
res5: RestrictedClass = RestrictedClass@88aa72
```

This seems to give you what you asked for: *"Is there any way to also have type restrictions on the Product?"*